# How to replace pipe with regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have this chain to which you want to replace all occurrences given the following pattern `\d{1}[|]`, only replace the pipe for space.

> CLL18|C MUNICIPIO LIBRE 4a SECC|CLL10|CALLE MPIO. LIBRE 4a
>   SECC|TknsPrs|MPIO. LIBRE 4a SECC.|CLL20|MPIO. LIBRE

and I would like to stay as follows:

> CLL18 C MUNICIPIO LIBRE 4a SECC|CLL10 CALLE MPIO. LIBRE 4a
>   SECC|TknsPrs|MPIO. LIBRE 4a SECC.|CLL20 MPIO. LIBRE

Is this possible with regular expressions??

Answer (score 4):

```
(?<=\d)\|
```

Try this.`re.sub(r"(?<=\d)\|"," ",test_string)`See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/25#python